# Allow a static page to show on a dynamic home blog page before the posts

Tags: homepage, blog-page

I am trying to figure out what is the best practice to allow a customizable static page to show on the top of the dynamic front home page. What I am asking is not using a custom page a such as front-page.php because I would like to setup "Front page displays - Your latest posts" in the Wordpress > Settings > Reading section and the dynamic page to be the front page. What is the way to add some javascript to functions.php or index.php or any other file to load a custom page before the dynamic page so the both pages will show on the home page. I have done it a long time ago and do not remember any more. This is the website I did it for http://superforma.org. The reason I am trying to do it that way is because I am trying to use the templates for the blog style from the theme I am using and do not want to just add the blog section and try to customize.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit your front-page template and before (or after) your loop, you need to make a call to `get_post()` so load your custom page. See [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) for details.

You can then render your customisable page on the homepage.

For example, if your special page ID is 42:

```
<?php 
   $custom_page = get_post(42);
   echo apply_filters('the_content', $custom_page->post_content);
?>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the response. I am trying not to use front-page.php and have setup wordpress to show blog on a front page instead of front to be a template page so I am assuming that index.php should be in charge of what is showing on that page. So am trying to add a static page I have designed in wordpress to that front dynamic blog page. I tried to use your advice but adding it to index.php and it didn't work by using the id of the static page.

Comment: check here http://letchowebs.com/Test2.png

Comment: My mistake - you need to change the echo line to use `$custom_page` rather than `$post`. If that fails, can you please do a `var_dump($custom_page);` and show the output?

Comment: Hey Alex, I have tried your recommendation  but it didn't work . Unfortunately I am not familiar with the var_dump function since I haven't done it for a long time so I wasn't  able to add it . Just to make sure I am doing the right thing , I am adding  custom page function to the index.php file.

Comment: check here: http://letchowebs.com/test2.png

Comment: No problem, you just need to write `$custom_page = get_post(42); var_dump($custom_page);` and this will show you what it has managed to find. We can always continue this on chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you. I am not really familiar with http://chat.stackexchange.com so not sure how to start the chat :S So I added the var_dump($custom_page); to the script and this is what came out on the top of the page right before the post feed: http://pet.imagelabproductions.com

Comment: That's correct, so the var_dump is showing you that $custom_page is a WP_Post object. There doesn't seem to be any content on the page which is why you don't see anything with `echo $custom_page->post_content`. Try adding something to the page and you will see it appear. I'll open a chat if you still can't get it working.

Comment: Ok let us go on the chat. I tried to start but wasn't able to determine how. So I had content on that page but I guess I deleted something and that is why it wasn't loading. I resubmitted the file and now it finally appeared :) Now for some reason it is braking the entire page and the script that was showing on the top of the page is still showing after the content. This is the front page: http://pet.imagelabproductions.com and this is the page I am trying to load on the top: http://pet.imagelabproductions.com/portfolio2016

Comment: Lets talk here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53152/room-for-alex-holsgrove-and-svetlozar-chat

Comment: Hey Alex, unfortunately I do not think I can participate in the chat room "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here." :S